# Count changes in a string from the previous row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, metadata

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i60uP.png)

```
Id    Input
1     A,B
2     B,C,D
3     E,F,G
4     G
```

i want to count the changes in the list, so we will compare within the list as well and with the previous ID list, my output should be like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytYJS.png)

```
 Id    Input     Output
 1     A,B        1
 2     B,C,D      2
 3     E,F,G      3
 4     G          0
```

(A,B) there are 1 change from A to B.
(B,C,D) B is already present as last element in the previous id, so there will be 2 changes from B to c and c to D.
(E,F,G) since E is not the last element of previous list so there will be three changes from previous D to current E, E to F and F to G.
for Id 4 there will be 0 changes as G is present in the last list as well.

How can I create a the output column counting these changes.

Comment: Why is `id 1` `output=1`, shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: It is 1 because there is one change from A to B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.
Assuming that the data-frame index is "Id",you can use a combination of `DataFrame.shift` and `DataFrame.iterrows()` to get this done, first you create a column with the values shifted by one, and a column for the output :

```
df['Input-1'] = df['Input'].shift(1).fillna('A' )
df['Output'] = 0
```

this will result in:

```
    Input Input-1  Output
Id
1     A,B       A       0
2   B,C,D     A,B       0
3   E,F,G   B,C,D       0
4       G   E,F,G       0
```

then you can iterate through the rows and set the output:

```
for id_, row in df.iterrows():
   df.at[id_, 'Output'] = len(set(row['Input-1'].split(',')[-1:]+row['Input'].split(',')))-1
```

The output will be :

```
    Input Input-1  Output
Id
1     A,B       A       1
2   B,C,D     A,B       2
3   E,F,G   B,C,D       3
4       G   E,F,G       0
```

Comment: In first Row output should be 1, from A to B only 1 change

Comment: Apparently, i misunderstood the question, this now should be correct, assuming that there will be no gaps between the letters

Comment: i am getting incorrect output in row 3, output is coming as 2 but it should be 3

Comment: Make sure you follow the steps, it should be 3

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are only asking for additions. Also your first case seems odd, going from empty list to a list with 2 items would seem to require 2 additions.

All you have to do is store a hashmap of the items in each list. When you go through the next list, you can check whether it is already there in O(1) time per item.

Comment: here is my code but not getting the correct output:                                                                         Data['key']=Data['Input']
Data['Output']=0
l1=[]
for i in range (1, len(Data)):
    if(Data.loc[i, 'key']!=Data.loc[i-1, 'key'].split(',')[-1]):
        Data.loc[i,'Output']=1
        l1=Data.loc[i,'Input'].split(',')
        if (Data.loc[i-1, 'Input'] not in l1):
            Data.loc[i, 'Output']=len(l1)